# homework - trying to calculate multiple flight stops between two cities?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This is for a database class, using Oracle DB 11g

```
Tables:

• Flight (flt_no, from_city, to_city, flt_distance, 
  flt_departs, flt_arrives, flt_price)

• Aircraft (craft_id, craft_name, cruising_range)

• Employee (emp_id, emp_name, emp_salary)

• Certified (emp_id, craft_id)
```

QUERY: A customer wants to travel from Madison to New York with no more than two changes of flight. List the choice of departures from Madison if the customer wants to arrive at New York by 6pm.

ANY Help is appreciate for this. I really don't even know where to start on this.

***EDIT***
This is what I've come up with so far. Please let me know if I'm on the right track at least please.

```
SELECT F.flt_no
  FROM Flight F
 WHERE F.from_city = 'Madison'
   AND F.to_city = 'New York'
   AND DATEPART(hh, F.flt_arrives) <= 18
 UNION
SELECT F.flt_no
  FROM Flight F
 WHERE (F.from_city = 'Madison'
        AND F.to_city IN (SELECT from_city
                            FROM Flight F
                           WHERE F.to_city = 'New York')
       )
    OR
       (F.to_city = 'New York'
        AND F.from_city IN (SELECT to_city
                              FROM Flight F
                             WHERE F.from_city = 'Madison')
        AND DATEPART(hh, F.flt_arrives) <= 18
       )
```

Comment: "*I have an unusual query request.*" No there is nothing unusual. Your table structure somewhat looks wonky. I can't guess because it depends upon your requirements.

Comment: Well, from what I'm used to, it's unusual. The table structure was the required design in the assignment, so I can't change that. What requirements do you mean? I just need to write any query that will return the results that I specified.

Comment: DATEPART is not Oracle syntax (except in EssBase, which doesn't really count)

Comment: @APC, or anyone, can you tell me how to query against the hour field alone. This is what you get when you look on google for your answers. I've read my textbook a thousand times and there is nothing that helps me regarding this question. This is why I asked it here. Someone please give me a hand.

Comment: @bOkeifus, the problem is you're reading your textbook rather than trying many, many, times to work out what your query does and what is wrong and how you can improve it. You can solve your date options by looking at [this site](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php).

Answer (score 6):

Think of the three cases:

1. A direct flight.
2. flight with 1 stop.
3. a flight with two stops.

Now start stepping through the cases.

For 1.  Look for flight that start and stop, you know where and you know when by, right?

For 2.  Think about those two flights.  Where will they start and end, what will be in common with the two flight.  What's the time criteria for each flight?

For 3.  Think about those 3 segments and the characteristics of each, including dependencies

Then you finally want the union of all these if all choice are to be shown.

This function: select `to_char(DATE,'HH24') may help.`

Answer (score 0):

As @Michael Durrant has given the answer I just want to contribute the solution in SQL format.Hope this will help.**Please check the Not Equal to sign.**

```
#Direct flight
select f.no
from flights f
where f.arrives=18:00 and (f.from='madison' and f.to='NewYork')

union

# Cases for one connecting flight

select f2.no 
from flights f1, flights f2
where f2.arrives=6pm and 
    f1.from='Madison' and f1.to<>'New York'
    and f1.to=f2.from and f2.to='New York'
    and f2.depart> f1.arrives
    and f2.arrives<'18:00'

union
#Cases involving two connecting flights 
select f3.no
from flights f1,flights f2, flights f3
where   f1.from='Madison'
    and f1.to=f2.from
    f1.to<>'New York'
    f2.to=f3.from
    f2.to<>'New York'
    and f3.to='New York'
    and f2.depart> f1.arrives   
    and f3.depart> f2.arrives

    and f3.arrives<'18:00'
```