# SQL query with no more than two changes of flight

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these tables in SQL Server:

- `Flights` (ﬂno: integer, from: string, to: string, distance: integer
  departs: time, arrives: time, price: real)
- `Aircraft` (aid: integer, aname: string, cruisingrange: integer)
- `Certified` (eid: integer, aid: integer)
- `Employees` (eid: integer, ename: string, salary: integer)

Note that the `Employees` relation describes pilots and other kinds of employees as well;
every pilot is certified for some aircraft, and only pilots are certified to ﬂy.

I want a query that find a customer wants to travel from Madison to New York with no more than two changes of ﬂight. List the choice of departure times from Madison if the customer
wants to arrive in NewYork by 6p.m.

I want a simple answer using nested queries.

---

Answer with the help of Michael Durrant Tip :

Think of the three cases:

1. A direct flight.
2. flight with 1 stop.
3. a flight with two stops.

Now start stepping through the cases.

For 1. Look for flight that start and stop, you know where and you know when by, right?

For 2. Think about those two flights. Where will they start and end, what will be in common with the two flight. What's the time criteria for each flight?

For 3. Think about those 3 segments and the characteristics of each, including dependencies

Then you finally want the union of all these if all choice are to be shown:

```
SELECT F.departs
FROM Flights F
WHERE F.ﬂno IN (( SELECT F0.ﬂno
FROM Flights F0
WHERE F0.from = ‘Madison’ AND F0.to = ‘New York’
AND F0.arrives < ‘18:00’ )
UNION
( SELECT F0.ﬂno
FROM Flights F0, Flights F1
WHERE F0.from = ‘Madison’ AND F0.to <> ‘New York’
AND F0.to = F1.from AND F1.to = ‘New York’
AND F1.departs > F0.arrives
AND F1.arrives < ‘18:00’ )
UNION
( SELECT F0.ﬂno
FROM Flights F0, Flights F1, Flights F2
WHERE F0.from = ‘Madison’
AND F0.to = F1.from
AND F1.to = F2.from
AND F2.to = ‘New York’
AND F0.to <> ‘New York’
AND F1.to <> ‘New York’
AND F1.departs > F0.arrives
AND F2.departs > F1.arrives
AND F2.arrives < ‘18:00’ ))
```

Comment: First show us your attempt and then maybe we'll help you.

Comment: Post sample data for all your tables, desired output based on it, what you have tried so far.

Comment: Okay show us your complex answer that doesn't use nested queries, we'll go from there.

Comment: @peterm Also DDL for the tables would be nice IMO.

Comment: i ve just found my answer here : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695016/homework-trying-to-calculate-multiple-flight-stops-between-two-cities?rq=1

Comment: Welcome to SO :) you did not see the about section, did you?

Comment: Wow that was lucky, same airports as well. Did you understand the answer?